# How is it possible, that nobody can track anyone on the bitcoin network?

Tags: privacy

Is it possible that a person on the bitcoin network cannot be tracked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Because one person can generate new public and private key for each transaction. Bitcoin coin Blockchain provides anonymity.

However, it's just possible if we are working proactively. Means Don't share confidential information regarding transactions or accounts with people. Moreover, as I already said, generate new addresses for each transaction. In addition, there are enormous best ways of being proactive on the bitcoin network. This [article](https://bitcoin.org/en/protect-your-privacy) would be helpful regarding learning the best ways.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer, the updated version is much better!

Answer (score 4):

> I was studying, no one can track a person on the bitcoin network. Is that true?

Users can be tracked IF they don't follow the best practices. Although lot of on-chain analysis and investigation works on assumptions.

How?

- Every transaction on-chain has lot of information associated with it including address, amount, type of transaction etc.
- Not every user runs their own full node with tor
- Some users share information related to transactions on social media

Best practices:

1. Use non-kyc non-custodial exchanges
2. Use full node with tor
3. Do not share information about transactions on social media
4. Use coinjoin, payjoin etc.
5. Do not reuse addresses